If an implication holds pointwise, can we informally take the supremum and the implication will still hold?
Notation and context. Consider the usual $n-$dimensional real space $\mathbb R^n$ and let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ stand for an arbitrary non-empty open subset. Moreover, consider function $f_{x,r}: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ which is dependent on certain elements $x \in \Omega$ and $r > 0$.
Question. Assume that $g,h,\varphi$ and $\phi$ are real-valued functions such that the expressions below make sense. Suppose that we have previously proved that
$$\tag{1} \varphi(f_{x,r}) \geqslant 1 \implies  g(f_{x,r}) \leqslant h(f_{x,r}) \leqslant \phi(f_{x,r}) $$
holds for all $x \in \Omega$ and $r > 0$. Can we informally take the supremum on this result and guarantee that
$$ \sup_{x \in \Omega, r > 0} \varphi(f_{x,r}) \geqslant 1 \implies \sup_{x \in \Omega, r > 0} g(f_{x,r}) \leqslant \sup_{x \in \Omega, r > 0} h(f_{x,r}) \leqslant \sup_{x \in \Omega, r > 0} \phi(f_{x,r}) \quad ? $$
My thoughts. I don't believe that the conclusion presented is necessarily true, although I couldn't build a proper counter-example. I will now try to expose my reasoning as best as I can. The main problem I see with the conclusion above is that when we assume that
$$ \sup_{x \in \Omega, r > 0} \varphi(f_{x,r}) \geqslant 1 $$
it isn't necessarily true that
$$ \varphi(f_{x,r}) \geqslant 1 $$
holds for all $x \in \Omega$ and $r > 0$. Thefore, the chain of inequalities $(1)$ doesn't necessarily hold for all elements $x \in \Omega$ and $r > 0$, which means that we can't just take the supremum in order to conclude the reasoning.
Further thoughts. I think that if we rewrite the question as "Suppose that we have previously proved that
$$ \tag{2} \varphi(f_{x,r}) \leqslant 1 \implies g(f_{x,r}) \leqslant h(f_{x,r}) \leqslant \phi(f_{x,r}) $$
holds for all fixed $x \in \Omega$ and $r > 0$. Can we informally take the supremum and guarantee that
$$ \sup_{x \in \Omega, r > 0} \varphi(f_{x,r}) \leqslant 1 \implies \sup_{x \in \Omega, r > 0} g(f_{x,r}) \leqslant \sup_{x \in \Omega, r > 0} h(f_{x,r}) \leqslant \sup_{x \in \Omega, r > 0} \phi(f_{x,r}) \quad ?" $$
The answer would be positive. I can provide my reasoning to achieve this result but I think it's beyond the scope of my question as of now.
Thanks for all the help in advance.

This is not possible. The implied statement is only true for those $x,r$, for which the left-hand side is true.
Consider the functions $f,g: \{0,1\} \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(0) = 0$, $f(1)=1$, $g(0)=2$, $g(1)=1$.
Then the following statement is true for all $x\in \{0,1\}$:
$$
f(x) \ge 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad g(x) \le1.
$$
However the statement
$$
\sup_{x\in \{0,1\}} f(x) \ge 1  \quad \Rightarrow \quad\sup_{x\in \{0,1\}} g(x) \le1
$$
is not true.

What is possible is to conclude from
$$
f(x) \le g(x) \quad \forall x
$$
the inequality
$$
\sup f(x) \le \sup g(x)
$$
by taking first the supremum on the right, then the supremum on the left.
